# Autofac- externally owned container?

Tags: autofac

I'm using an Autofac container for the entire lifetime of my application, but I want to dispose the components myself.

I.E if I have `builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()`, I don't want the container to keep references of `SomeType` which will keep those alive even if not referenced anywhere else (if `RegisterInstance` is used OTOH, then of course the container must keep a reference to the singleton).

I can see that I can do `builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().ExternallyOwned()` which solves my problem for one type, but I don't want to write it for every type, and more importantly I also use `builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());` which doesn't give me the option of using `ExternallyOwned`.

Is there a way to specify "ExternallyOwned" for the entire container? Or, to put it another way, tell the container to disable the entire dispose feature and not keep references for objects it doesn't need?

Comment: I'd consider extension methods on the ContainerBuilder so that you could write builder.RegisterExternalType<SomeType>() and get what you wanted without explicitly calling two methods everywhere.

Comment: That's not good enough, because as I said, I'm also using `builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());`

Comment: Ah. I see. I missed that part. Then you're left with writing your own registration source as well, I suppose. And honestly, if you look at how slim that source is, that's not really that big a job. :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. I didn't think to look how that source was implemented. Yeah, it seems like it's very doable just to write my own source which mimics it, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to disable container disposal services. You might try to hook in with [something like the logging module](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) but I could see that not working 100% and missing edge cases of you're not careful.

Automatic tracking and disposal is a pretty common container feature. I'd recommend instead of fighting it you refactor your code to embrace it. It'll make life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't really see how I can refactor my code to embrace auto disposal. I mean, it's a really convenient feature to have when you're doing unit-of-work type of workflows, where once you finish your work, you dispose of the container and everything with it. But, in my case, I'm writing a game engine and using the container as a way to allow customizing everything. There's no unit of work, the game developer can spawn an enemy or load a texture/sound effect whenever she/he wants throughout the game, so the life of the container and its created objects are not bound at all.

Comment: If this is the answer (whether it solves the problem or not, it's the actual answer to the question), please accept it so I can get credit.

Comment: I'm still hoping somebody will manage to come up with a magical solution. If there's no answer in a few days, I'll accept your answer.